# Merging all feature classes with same name nested in multiple geodatabases using ArcPy says feature class already exists?

Tags: arcpy, merge

I'm following very closely this topic [Merging all feature classes with same name nested in multiple geodatabases using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254711/merging-all-feature-classes-with-same-name-nested-in-multiple-geodatabases-using), it seems very useful to my python script

this is the script I following from made by Emil Brundage (answered Sep 8 '17 at 15:21):

```
import arcpy
import os

workspace = "C:/Wiley/P1/gis"
outdir = "C:/Wiley/P1/gis/HK80.gdb"

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Polygon")
di = {}

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
          for filename in filenames:
             fcFullPath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
             #try adding feature class to dictionary with already-existing key
             try: di [filename] += [fcFullPath]
             #key not in dictionary yet. Create key
             except: di [filename] = [fcFullPath]

#iterate dictionary
for filename in di:
    #get merge feature classes
    mergeFcs = di [filename]
    output = os.path.join(outdir, os.path.basename(fcFullPath) + "_merge")
    arcpy.Merge_management(mergeFcs, output)
```

However, when I run the script I get a message error show up, a feature class already exists. The script does exactly what I want, but how could I fix the script to avoid this error type.

Following the suggestion from amasephy add the arcpy.Exists and arcpy.Delete_management function on my script:

```
workspace = r'...\GDBESTATALES_PRUEBA'
outdir = r'...\GDB_Nacional.gdb'

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Polygon")
di = {}

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
          for filename in filenames:
             fcFullPath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
             #try adding feature class to dictionary with already-existing key
             try: di [filename] += [fcFullPath]
             #key not in dictionary yet. Create key
             except: di [filename] = [fcFullPath]

#iterate dictionary
for filename in di:
    #get merge feature classes
    mergeFcs = di [filename]
    output = os.path.join(outdir, os.path.basename(fcFullPath) + "_merge")
    arcpy.Merge_management(mergeFcs, output)
    if arcpy.Exists(output):
     arcpy.Delete_management(output)
```

However, nothing happens what I want it, the only one happens is the script takes the last geodatabase and save the last feature class in the other feature class (GDB_Nacional.gdb), that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [arcpy.Exists](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/exists.htm) function.  If the output name exists, then append a numerical digit to the output.  Alternatively, use [arcpy.Delete_management](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete.htm) to delete the feature that already exists.

Comment: Thaks for answer, I´m gonna try, Thanks for you help

Comment: Dear amasephy. I tryed to use arcpy.Exists function and arcpy.Delete_management, nothing happens what I want it, the only one happens is the script takes the last geodatabase and save the last feature class in the other feature class (GDB_Nacional.gdb), thats all.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried with the functions I posted above?

Comment: Dear amasephy, already I posted my script modified with the functions, I don't know where put the functions

Comment: You need to put the test for an existing feature class before the merge function.